# Pandas calculate new column from two other column variables within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This problem seemed simple to me but i have spend a couple of days on it and have not found anything as of yet...

To restate the question:  How do I calculate a new column in a pandas dataframe whose value is the returned result of a function that takes two other variables as args that are located in the same dataframe.

Here is a simplified example of the dataframe I am working with.

```
ix  sat_id  datetime            signal
0   13      11/13/2015 16:33    654884
1   13      11/13/2015 16:33    654883
2   87      11/13/2015 16:33    657889
3   87      11/13/2015 16:33    558774
4   87      11/13/2015 16:33    555222
5   99      11/13/2015 16:33    444555
6   99      11/13/2015 16:33    444333
```

I have a function that returns ephemeris altitude that takes global arguments for lat/lon, a variable argument for datetime and list of two line elements that is keyed off of satid simplified as follows.

```
def ephem_func(datetime,tle[satid],lat,lon):
    do_ephemeris_calcs...
    return altitude
```

Since my function is dependent on satid, and datetime that are both found inside my dataframe I was hoping to do something like this:

```
df['altitude'] = (df['datetime'], df['sat_id']).map(lambda x, y: ephem_func(x,tle[y],lat,lon))
```

However, this is not a thing and no matter how many times I say "python please" it does not work.

I also tried using pandas groupby to solve this as follows:

```
grouped = df.groupby('sat_id')

for key, item in grouped:
    item['altitude'] = item['datetime'].map(lambda x: ephem_func(x,tle[key],lat,lon))
```

However, using this approach i do not think i am actually assigning values back to my original dataframe. If I modify the dataframe being assigned to represent the original as follows:

```
df['altitude'] = item['datetime'].map(lambda x: ephem_func(x,tle[key], lat,lon))
```

Then i run into the problem of each new iteration over the grouped data assigns new values back to the original dataframe, but overwrites the rows from previous iterations with nan.

Desired result: Pass two variables contained within my dataframe (sat_id and datetime) into my function, and have the returned value assigned as the new column.

```
index   sat_id  datetime            signal  altitude
0       13      11/13/2015 16:33    654884  45
1       13      11/13/2015 16:33    654883  65
2       87      11/13/2015 16:33    657889  -45
3       87      11/13/2015 16:33    558774  90
4       87      11/13/2015 16:33    555222  88
5       99      11/13/2015 16:33    444555  77
6       99      11/13/2015 16:33    444333  66
```

Any guidance is appreciated here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have not found a very pythonic or Pandas-esque solution to this, but I did modify my big picture logic to obtain what I wanted using groupby and some serious data shuffling...

remember that my simplified function is structured like so:

```
def ephem_func(datetime,tle[satid],lat,lon):
    do_ephemeris_calcs...
    return altitude
```

I have data as follows

```
ix  sat_id  datetime            signal
0   13      11/13/2015 16:33    654884
1   13      11/13/2015 16:33    654883
2   87      11/13/2015 16:33    657889
3   87      11/13/2015 16:33    558774
4   87      11/13/2015 16:33    555222
5   99      11/13/2015 16:33    444555
6   99      11/13/2015 16:33    444333
```

here is my solution:

```
grouped = df.groupby('sat_id')

for key,item in grouped:
    date_range = []
    ix_range = []
    date_range = item['datetime']
    ix_range = item['ix']

    for date,ix in zip(date_range,ix_range):
        satlist.append(key)
        datelist.append(date)
        ixlist.append(ix)
        alt = ephem_func(date,tle[key],lat,lon)
        altitude.append(alt)
```

Now that I have all these lists, I can create a new dataframe 'results' merge the date back with the original dataframe using the ix as the merge key to make sure everything stays lined up
    results = pandas.DataFrame()

```
results['datetime'] = datelist
results['ix'] = ixlist
results['sat_id'] = satlist
results['altitude'] = altitude

final=pd.merge(df,results,on='ix')
```

This worked for me and merged the calculated altitude into one dataframe with the rest of the data that I started with.

If you have a more efficient way of doing this please respond!

Thanks